# Conditional means and measurable functions

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $f$ a measurable function and $X$ a random variable. Is the following equality always true?

$$\mathbb E[f(X)|f(X)] = \mathbb E[f(X)|X] $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $f(X)$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(f(X))$ and hence also with respect to $\sigma(X)$ since $\sigma(f(X))\subseteq \sigma(X)$. In particular, both conditional expectations are just $f(X)$.

Comment: Please @StefanHansen, does $f$ needs to be measurable for the equality to be true?

Comment: @gagaouthu: You need $f(X)$ to be a random variable in order for the conditional expectation of $f(X)$ to even be defined, so yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome.